# Classes generated from XSD does not work with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, onix

I need to read some XML files that follow the ONIX standard
See: http://www.editeur.org/93/Release-3.0-Downloads/

To do this i downloaded the ONIX 3.0 XSD:
http://www.editeur.org/files/ONIX%203/ONIX_BookProduct_XSD_schema+codes_Issue_25.zip

Using the downloaded XSD and this command "xsd your.xsd /classes" i created classes that i want to use.

When trying to create a new Xml Serializer like so:

```
var xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model.ONIX.editeur.ONIXMessage));
```

I get and exception

> "There was an error reflecting type 'Model.ONIX.editeur.ONIXMessage'."

When i drill down through the inner exceptions i end up with this message:

> "{"Member 'Text' cannot be encoded using the XmlText attribute. You
>   may use the XmlText attribute to encode primitives, enumerations,
>   arrays of strings, or arrays of XmlNode."}"

I am not sure what to do, is something wrong with the XSD? Any suggestions?!

**Edit**

```
public static List<Model.ONIX.editeur.Product> GetProductsDataFromOnixFile(string onixFileLocation)
    {
        var xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model.ONIX.editeur.ONIXMessageRefname));

        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(onixFileLocation))
        {
            if (xmls.CanDeserialize(reader))
            {
                var onixMessage = (Model.ONIX.editeur.ONIXMessage)xmls.Deserialize(reader);
                return onixMessage.Items.OfType<Model.ONIX.editeur.Product>().ToList();
            }

            throw new Exception(string.Format("Cant read the file {0} as Onix", onixFileLocation));
        }
    }
```

Comment: which xsd did you turn into classes (there are 4 xsds in your zip file)?

Comment: One of the classes created from the XSD. However this makes me think that i might be trying to use the wrong class to initialize the serializer

Comment: ONIX_BookProduct_3.0_reference

Comment: The file i'm trying to read is define like this:

"<ONIXMessage release="3.0" xmlns="http://www.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference">"

If using "Model.ONIX.editeur.ONIXMessageRefname" for the XmlSerializer i dont get the reflecting exception. But i cannot read the file.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but I assume others with specific Onix issues will run into this.

Here is how I got it to work.

In the reference xsd are two includes in the top. Here I copy/pasted the other two files in.

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="ONIX_BookProduct_CodeLists.xsd" />
<xs:include schemaLocation="ONIX_XHTML_Subset.xsd" />
```

I.e. these lines are replaced in the file with the corresponding file.

Then I did the

```
xsd ONIX_BookProduct_3.0_reference.xsd /classes
```

And then it generates the .cs file. And the only issue I had here was I had to remove a text attribute from all fields that was e.g. List147, but not from the fields that was string. E.g. I had to remove the attribute from generated code like this:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
public List121 textscript {
    get {
        return this.textscriptField;
```

but not from attributes like this

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
public string Value {
    get {
        return this.valueField;
```